# How to send chat invite to an user using XMPP java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp

I am using google appengine (Java) I want my application to send chat invite to an user , how to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

XMPP Java API Overview - Google App Engine - Google Code

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html